# update table as we click on the stacked highchart based on some logic

Tags: highcharts

Here I want to select the particular row from the table as I click on the stacked graph. I am new to Highcharts. I was wondering if I can pass the value from stacked chart to select an option of the table so that table gets dynamically updated for a specific stack. There are two different div one for a chart and another for table. How can I pass the name or any attribute of the chart, say I want to pass the name attribute of the stack which is the value of the select option to the select dropdown list whose id="myInput".

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").change("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });

Highcharts.chart('container', {
            colors: ['red','green'],
         chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Status of E-Muster Date Wise'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['10/05/2018', '11/05/2018', '12/05/2018', '13/05/2018', '14/05/2018']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total E-Muster Issued'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
          
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        
                    }
                }  
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Not submitted',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]  
            }, {
                name: 'Submitted',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <div class="e_container">
          <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        
          <div class="e_container">
            <h5>Information</h5>
        <select id="myInput">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option id="fd" value="10/05/2018">10/05/2018</option>
    <option id="cd" value="11/05/2018">11/05/2018</option>
    <option id="gh" value="12/05/2018">12/05/2018</option>
    </select>
            <table>
              <thead><tr>
                <th>E-MR No</td>
                <th>Contact Person</td>
                <th>Status</td>
                <th>Intimated</td>
                <th>Medium of Intimation</td>
                <th>Submitted after Dealine</td>
                <th>Date</td>
              </tr></thead>
              <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>shahnawaz</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>No</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>10/05/2018</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>185</td>
                <td>Vidhya</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>SMS</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>11/05/2018</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>165</td>
                <td>Akshay</td>
                <td>Submitted</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>SMS</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>12/05/2018</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>967</td>
                <td>Vidhya</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>SMS</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>13/05/2018</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>356</td>
                <td>Rakesh</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>SMS</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>14/05/2018</td>
              </tr></tbody>
            </table>
            
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [point click events](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click) to capture the click. Inside the callback `this` refers to the point object which has `category` prop which, in your exampe, is the date used in select input.

In the callback change the value of the select.

```
function changeValue(value) {
  $("#myInput").val(value)
  $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
}
```

plotOptions:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,

    },
    point: {
      events: {
        click() {
          changeValue(this.category)
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

live exmaple: https://jsfiddle.net/nwj62h4f/

Comment: @marganfree thanks a lot...I need to further extend my question...If you can please help here again it will be really a great help ...Now suppose that today is 11/05/2018. Now as the date in the calendar gets change I want my stack representing the previous date data (say of 10/05/2018). Here the colour of  series.name=Not submitted should change to yellow and series.name=Not submitted sould change to "series.name=Pending" (series.name=submitted will remain same i.e color=green) and for date after 11/05/2018 should chage to blue and series.name to "To Submit". Is it possible to do?

Comment: Create a new question with the issue, description and the minimal and complete code - a live example, e.g. in jsfiddle, would be the most helpful.